# Custom message for InvalidConstraintException

Tags: c#, exception

I'm deleting a DataRow which fails due to foreign contraints. An InvalidConstraintException is thrown which I would like to catch, log, and then display to the user a message saying it failed to delete due to *table name* using it.

With a ConstraintException it sets info on the DataSet such as if there are errors on a particular row. In this case there is enough information for me to generate a message by tapping into that info. InvalidConstraintException doesn't seem to set any of that info.

Is there anyway I can find which tables are involved when an InvalidConstraintException is thrown?

Comment: Only way I can think to is by putting the try-catch around the code that is doing the deleting and keeping track yourself of the table you're deleting from.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the datarows' table, Please try DataRow.Table

Comment: I'm trying first to determine if a DataRow is linked to the InvalidContraintException that is thrown. Then, if I can determine that I would use DataRow.Table to get any table info I might require.